# Angular 9 Error 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular

Bom dia!
Estou fazendo uma função para cada click do usuário em um determinado botão aparecer o campo para ele add outro telefone. Segue imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o trecho html:

```
            <div *ngFor="let phone of s.controls; let i = index" class="list-group list-group-flush">
               <h3>Complementar Telefone</h3>
             <div [formGroup]="phon" class="row">
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="phone">Celular <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
                <input mask="(00) 00000-0000"  formControlName="phone" type="text" class="form-control" id="celular" placeholder="">
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
   
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-middle">
              <button (click)="onChangePhone()" class="ml-auto mr-auto btn btn-outline-info pt-2 pb-2 btn-sm mb-2" type="button"> + Adicionar Telefone </button>
            </div>
             </form>
```

Esse é o trecho do component:

```
  
  public basicInfo: FormGroup;
 
  }

  this.basicInfo = this.formBuilder.group({
      
      phone: [this.currentUser.user.phone, Validators.required],
    });


  get s() { return this.basicInfo.controls; }
  get p() { return this.s.phones as FormArray; }

ngOnInit() {}

 setBasicInfo(basicInfo) {
    this.basicInfo.patchValue({
      numberOfPhones: basicInfo.length
    })
    basicInfo.forEach(element => {
      this.p.push(this.formBuilder.group({
        phone: element.phone,
        
      }));
    });
  }

   onChangePhone(){
    //return console.log('Testando')
    const numberOfPhones = this.basicInfo.value.numberOfPhones;
    this.basicInfo.patchValue({
      numberOfPhones: numberOfPhones + 1
    })

    if (this.p.length < numberOfPhones) {
      for (let i = this.p.length; i < numberOfPhones; i++) {
        this.p.push(this.formBuilder.group({
          phone: ['', Validators.required],
         
        }));
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = this.p.length; i >= numberOfPhones; i--) {
        this.p.removeAt(i);
      }
    }
   
  }
```

Quando clico no botão Adicionar Telefone aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me por favor?

Comment: você tem que usar o formArray inves do group

Comment: Você refere se no html?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Crie uma variável no seu component:

```
phones: FormArray;
```

2 - Coloque sua div dentro de outra assim:

```
<div  formArrayName="phones" >
    <div *ngFor="let phone of s.controls; let i:index">
    //...
    </div>
</div>
```

3 - Adicione formGroupName com seu *index* na sua div:

```
<div *ngFor="let phone of s.controls; let i:index"  [formGroupName]="i">
```

4 - Você precisa declarar seu form phones como um array:

```
  this.basicInfo = this.formBuilder.group({
      phones: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    });
```

5 - Remova esse formGroup, não é necessário:

```
<div [formGroup]="phon" class="row">
```

6 - Crie uma função para iniciar seus phones adicionados dentro de cada array com as validações:

```
initPhone(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        phone: this.formBuilder.control('',[Validators.required]),
    });
}
```

7 - Modifique sua função de add phone para:

```
addPhone(){
    this.phones.push(this.initPhone());
}
```

8 - Crie uma função para remover os phones adicionados:

```
removePhone(index:number){
    this.phones = this.basicInfo.get('phones') as FormArray;
    this.phones.removeAt(index);
}
```

9 - Inclua uma âncora em seu html para remover telefones adicionados:

```
<a  (click)="removePhone(i)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Excluir</a>
```

10 - E se for uma página de editar, para inserir os phones (de um ajax, por exemplo) é só fazer assim:

```
this.phones = this.form.get('phones') as FormArray;
this.phones.removeAt(0); // Só para garantir que não veio populado com o array vazio.
for (let i = 0; i <= (ajaxData.phones.length-1); i++) {
    this.phones.push(this.initPhone());
    this.phones.at(i).patchValue({
        phone: ajaxData.phones[i].phone, // preencha de acordo com sua variável.
    })
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraços!

Comment: Oh meu brother ajudou e muito!! agora preciso vê uma forma de salvar isso no banco. Muito obrigado!